# Java: How to get assigned numeric values for String input

Tags: java, string, numerical-methods

I want to assign specific values to alphabets (below in the code) and then calculate its
total added output which is provided by input string, which I am not getting. E.g. Kamran= 2+1+4+2+1+5 = 15 or abc = 1+2+3 = 6. 
Via this code I only get the output of the last digit.
Thanks in Advance! Regards!!!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class p1 {

    static int addition;
    static char Kamran;
    static int string1;
    static int total;
    final static int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=8,g=3,h=5,i=1,j=1,k=2,l=3,m=4,n=5,o=7,p=8,q=1,r=2,s=3,t=4,u=6,v=6,w=6,x=5,y=1,z=7;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String userInput = in.readLine();
        for(int ai=0;ai<userInput.length();ai++){
            string1 = (int)userInput.charAt(ai);
        }
        int adder=0;

        if(string1=='k')
            {adder = 2 + adder ; }
        if(string1=='a')
            {adder = 1 + adder ; }
        if(string1=='m')
            {adder = 4 + adder ; }
        if(string1=='r')
            {adder = 2 + adder ; }
        if(string1=='b')
            {adder = 2 + adder ; }
        if(string1=='n')
            {adder = 5 + adder ; }

        total=adder;
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your addition should happen inside of the loop not after it?

Comment: where are used your final static variables?

Comment: Move the brace that's right above 'int adder=0;' to right below System.out.println(total);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class p1 {       
        final static int    a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=8,g=3,h=5,i=1,j=1,k=2,l=3,m=4,n=5,o=7,p=8,q=1,r=2,s=3,t=4,u=6,v=6,w=6,x=5,y=1,z=7;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String userInput = in.readLine();
            String input;
            int adder = 0;
            System.out.println(" userInput " + userInput);
            for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++){
                input = userInput.charAt(i) + "";
                System.out.println(" input " + input);
                if (input.equals("k"))
                    adder += k; 
                if (input.equals("a"))
                    adder += a;;
                if (input.equals("m"))
                    adder += m;;
                if (input.equals("r"))
                    adder += r;
                if (input.equals("b"))
                    adder += b;
                if (input.equals("n"))
                    adder += n;
            }                    
            System.out.println(" adder " + adder);  
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    public int desiredMethod(String input, Function<Character, Integer> conversion){
        String inputRevised = input.toLowerCase();
        int output = 0;
        for(int i=0 ; i<inputRevised.length() ; i++)
            output = output + conversion.apply(inputRevised.charAt(i));
        return output;
    }
```

That way, the same method can be used with more than one map character»integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   int adder=0;
   for(int ai=0;ai<userInput.length();ai++){
        string1 = (int)userInput.charAt(ai);
    if(string1=='k')
        {adder = 2 + adder ; }
    if(string1=='a')
        {adder = 1 + adder ; }
    if(string1=='m')
        {adder = 4 + adder ; }
    if(string1=='r')
        {adder = 2 + adder ; }
    if(string1=='b')
        {adder = 2 + adder ; }
    if(string1=='n')
        {adder = 5 + adder ; }
 }

 System.out.println(adder);
```

You aren't adding inside the loop you will only get the value of the last character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {


    /*final static int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 8, g = 3, h = 5,
            i = 1, j = 1, k = 2, l = 3, m = 4, n = 5, o = 7, p = 8, q = 1,
            r = 2, s = 3, t = 4, u = 6, v = 6, w = 6, x = 5, y = 1, z = 7;*/

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String userInput = (in.readLine()).toLowerCase();

        HashMap<Character,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        hm.put('a', 1);     hm.put('b', 2);     hm.put('c', 3);     hm.put('d', 4);     hm.put('e', 5);
        hm.put('f', 8);     hm.put('g', 3);     hm.put('h', 5);     hm.put('i', 1);     hm.put('j', 1);
        hm.put('k', 2);     hm.put('l', 3);     hm.put('m', 4);     hm.put('n', 5);     hm.put('o', 7);
        hm.put('p', 8);     hm.put('q', 1);     hm.put('r', 2);     hm.put('s', 3);     hm.put('t', 4);
        hm.put('u', 6);     hm.put('v', 6);     hm.put('w', 6);     hm.put('x', 5);     hm.put('y', 1);
        hm.put('z', 7);

        int total = 0;

        for(int ai=0;ai<userInput.length();ai++){
            total+= hm.get(userInput.charAt(ai));
        }

        System.out.println(total);
    }

}
```